# Texto en botón aleatorio. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

```js
var cajaPaises = [{
            pais: "Noruega",
            capital: "oslo",
            continente: "Europa"
        }, {
            pais: "Polonia",
            capital: "Varsovia",
            continente: "Europa"
        }, {
            pais: "Francia",
            capital: "París",
            continente: "Europa"
        },
        {
            pais: "Grecia",
            capital: "Atenas",
            continente: "Europa"
        }, {
            pais: "Italia",
            capital: "Roma",
            continente: "Europa"
        }, {
            pais: "Libia",
            capital: "Trípoli",
            continente: "Africa"
        }, {
            pais: "Argelia",
            capital: "Argel",
            continente: "Africa"

        },
        {
            pais: "Marruecos",
            capital: "Rabat",
            continente: "Africa"
        },
        {
            pais: "Sudán",
            capital: "Jartum",
            continente: "Africa"
        }, {
            pais: "Egipto",
            capital: "El Cairo",
            continente: "Africa"
        }, {
            pais: "India",
            capital: "Nueva Delhi",
            continente: "Asia"
        }, {
            pais: "China",
            capital: "Pekin",
            continente: "Asia"
        }, {
            pais: "Tibet",
            capital: "Lhasa",
            continente: "Asia"
        }, {
            pais: "Irán",
            capital: "Teherán",
            continente: "Asia"
        }, {
            pais: "Japon",
            capital: "Tokio",
            continente: "Asia"
        }, {
            pais: "Canadá",
            capital: "Ottawa",
            continente: "America"
        }, {
            pais: "Mexico",
            capital: "Ciudad de Méjico",
            continente: "America"
        }, {
            pais: "Brasil",
            capital: "Brasilia",
            continente: "America"
        }, {
            pais: "Colombia",
            capital: "Bogotá",
            continente: "America"
        }, {
            pais: "Ecuador",
            capital: "Quito",
            continente: "America"
        }, {
            pais: "Australia",
            capital: "Camberra",
            continente: "Oceania"
        }, {
            pais: "Nauro",
            capital: "No tiene",
            continente: "Oceania"
        }];






var incorrectas = ["Tanzania", "Alejandría", "Jerusalén", "Viena", "Bruselas", "Florida", "Swakopmund", "Blantyre", "Mwanza", ]

    //--------------JUEGO-----------------------



    var numeroAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * cajaPaises.length);

    var paisAleatorio = cajaPaises[numeroAleatorio]["pais"];


    $("#pais1").text(paisAleatorio) //Primer boton del juego.


    var capitalAleatorio = cajaPaises[numeroAleatorio]["capital"];
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  
  <div class="a"><button class="pais" id="pais1"></button></div>
  <div class="b"><button class="opciones" id="bt1"></button></div>
  <div class="c"><button class="opciones"id="bt2"></button></div>
  <div class="d"><button class="opciones" id="bt3"></button></div>
  

 
 
 
 
   
       </div>
```

Llevo semanas buscando solución a mi código...Me he quedado estancanda en intentar que un texto aparezca de forma aleatoria en tres botones.
He probado varias formas sin éxito. 
Agradecería que alguien me pudiese ayudar.
El problema lo tengo para hacer que la capital de la respuesta correcta aparezca aleatoriamente en uno de los tres botones con la clase "opciones".
 **Saludos y gracias!**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Juego</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilo.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body class="body2">
  
  <div id="number"></div>
   
   <div class="contenido">



<div class="continentes">
 <img  id="imagenes" src="mapa-de-europa.jpg" alt="mapa de europa">
 <img  class="imagenes1" src="Asia.jpg" alt="Asia">
 <img  class="imagenes1"  src="AFRIQUE.jpg" alt="africa">
 <img  class="imagenes1"   src="australia.jpg" alt="Oceania">
 <img  class="imagenes1"   src="america.jpg" alt="America">
 </div>
 
<!----RELOJ-------------------->


    <div id="reloj"></div>

 
 <!-------FIN RELOJ--------------->




  <div class="grid-container">
  
  <div class="a"><button class="pais" id="pais1"></button></div>
  <div class="b"><button class="opciones" id="bt1"></button></div>
  <div class="c"><button class="opciones"id="bt2"></button></div>
  <div class="d"><button class="opciones" id="bt3"></button></div>
  

 
 
 
 
   
       </div>
       
       
       
    </div>
    

   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: coloca tu código HTML.

Comment: Gracias por el apunte, estoy intentándolo, pero aquí no me permite ponerlo completo...a ver si consigo insertar un poco más...

Comment: Por lo que veo los botones los tienes con identificadores, pero estás intentando cambiar el valor con "text", ¿haz intentado esto? $("#bt1").attr('value', 'paisAleatorio ');

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! Quizá no me haya expresado bien...consigo poner los paises en el primer boton, y si escribo $(".opciones").text(capitalAleatorio) consigo que aparezca la capital correspondiente al país pero, en el botón seguido del país....lo que estoy buscando hacer es que "capitalAleatorio" se muestre aleatoriamente en los tres botones con la clase "opciones" o mediante su identificador...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí lo resolví, fui probando con 3 países para validar que no se repitan en las respuestas, ya le aumentas todo tu array de `cajaPaises`:

```js
const cajaPaises = [
  {
    pais: "Noruega",
    capital: "oslo",
    continente: "Europa"
  },
  {
    pais: "Polonia",
    capital: "Varsovia",
    continente: "Europa"
  },
  {
    pais: "Francia",
    capital: "París",
    continente: "Europa"
  }
];

var incorrectas = [
  "Tanzania",
  "Alejandría",
  "Jerusalén",
  "Viena",
  "Bruselas",
  "Florida",
  "Swakopmund",
  "Blantyre",
  "Mwanza"
];

//--------------JUEGO-----------------------

const cajaPaisesLength = cajaPaises.length;

const indicePaisAleatorio = getRandomIndex(cajaPaisesLength);

const paisAleatorio = cajaPaises[indicePaisAleatorio].pais;

// texto con el país en el boton principal
setTextToButton($("#pais1"), cajaPaises[indicePaisAleatorio].pais);

// target a todos los botones con el prefix id="bt*"
const botonesOpciones = $("button[id^='bt']");

const botonRptaCorrecta =
  botonesOpciones[getRandomIndex(botonesOpciones.length)];

// texto con la capital en botonRptaCorrecta
setTextToButton($(botonRptaCorrecta), cajaPaises[indicePaisAleatorio].capital);

assignTextToButtons();

/**
 * asigna texto a los botones donde no esté la respuesta correcta
 * y valida que no se repitan las capitales
 *
 */
function assignTextToButtons() {
  botonesOpciones.each((index, boton) => {
    // asigna texto en boton si está vacío (donde no esté la rpta)
    if ($(boton).text() === "") {
      let capitalRandom = "";

      // mientras la capital no sea repetida vuelve a elegir una aleatoria
      do {
        capitalRandom = cajaPaises[getRandomIndex(cajaPaisesLength)].capital;
      } while (!validateCapitalNotRepeat(capitalRandom));

      setTextToButton($(boton), capitalRandom);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Asigna texto al elemento
 *
 * @param {node} element
 * @param {String} text
 */
function setTextToButton(element, text) {
  element.text(text);
}

/**
 * retorna un número (aleatorio - 1) para ser usado como indice aleatorio de los arrays
 *
 * @param {number} numeroLimite
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getRandomIndex(numeroLimite) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (numeroLimite - 1));
}

/**
 * retorna si es válido que la capital no esté repetida como texto en el boton de la rpta correcta
 *
 * @param {String} capital
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function validateCapitalNotRepeat(capital) {
  let isValid = true;
  botonesOpciones.each((index, el) => {
    if ($(el).text() === capital) isValid = false;
  });

  return isValid;
}
```

```css
#pais1 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="number"></div>

    <div class="contenido">

        <div class="continentes">
            <img id="imagenes" src="mapa-de-europa.jpg" alt="mapa de europa">
            <img class="imagenes1" src="Asia.jpg" alt="Asia">
            <img class="imagenes1" src="AFRIQUE.jpg" alt="africa">
            <img class="imagenes1" src="australia.jpg" alt="Oceania">
            <img class="imagenes1" src="america.jpg" alt="America">
        </div>

        <!----RELOJ-------------------->
        <div id="reloj"></div>
        <!-------FIN RELOJ--------------->

        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="a">
                <button class="pais" id="pais1"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="b">
                <button class="opciones" id="bt1"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="c">
                <button class="opciones" id="bt2"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="d">
                <button class="opciones" id="bt3"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Agradezco enormemente tu ayuda y la tendré en cuenta. LLevo tantos días a vueltas con el código que intentaré dar con la respuesta a el código que tengo, se trata de algo personal....pero me quito el sombrero por las molestias que te has tomado, lo rápido y efectivo que ha sido tu código. Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var cajaPaises = [{
        pais: "Noruega",
        capital: "oslo",
        continente: "Europa"
    }, {
        pais: "Polonia",
        capital: "Varsovia",
        continente: "Europa"
    }, {
        pais: "Francia",
        capital: "París",
        continente: "Europa"
    },
    {
        pais: "Grecia",
        capital: "Atenas",
        continente: "Europa"
    }, {
        pais: "Italia",
        capital: "Roma",
        continente: "Europa"
    }, {
        pais: "Libia",
        capital: "Trípoli",
        continente: "Africa"
    }, {
        pais: "Argelia",
        capital: "Argel",
        continente: "Africa"

    },
    {
        pais: "Marruecos",
        capital: "Rabat",
        continente: "Africa"
    },
    {
        pais: "Sudán",
        capital: "Jartum",
        continente: "Africa"
    }, {
        pais: "Egipto",
        capital: "El Cairo",
        continente: "Africa"
    }, {
        pais: "India",
        capital: "Nueva Delhi",
        continente: "Asia"
    }, {
        pais: "China",
        capital: "Pekin",
        continente: "Asia"
    }, {
        pais: "Tibet",
        capital: "Lhasa",
        continente: "Asia"
    }, {
        pais: "Irán",
        capital: "Teherán",
        continente: "Asia"
    }, {
        pais: "Japon",
        capital: "Tokio",
        continente: "Asia"
    }, {
        pais: "Canadá",
        capital: "Ottawa",
        continente: "America"
    }, {
        pais: "Mexico",
        capital: "Ciudad de Méjico",
        continente: "America"
    }, {
        pais: "Brasil",
        capital: "Brasilia",
        continente: "America"
    }, {
        pais: "Colombia",
        capital: "Bogotá",
        continente: "America"
    }, {
        pais: "Ecuador",
        capital: "Quito",
        continente: "America"
    }, {
        pais: "Australia",
        capital: "Camberra",
        continente: "Oceania"
    }, {
        pais: "Nauro",
        capital: "No tiene",
        continente: "Oceania"
    }];
```

//    var capitales = "";

```
cajaPaises[0].pais;


var incorrectas = ["Tanzania", "Alejandría", "Jerusalén", "Viena", "Bruselas", "Florida", "Swakopmund", "Blantyre", "Mwanza", ]

//--------------JUEGO-----------------------



var numeroAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * cajaPaises.length);

var paisAleatorio = cajaPaises[numeroAleatorio]["pais"];


$("#pais1").text(paisAleatorio) //Primer boton del juego.


var capitalAleatorio = cajaPaises[numeroAleatorio]["capital"];
```

/*-------------------RESPUESTA CORRECTA EN BOTON ALEATORIO----------------*/

```
posicionAleatoria = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

var capitales = cajaPaises[numeroAleatorio]["capital"];

console.log(posicionAleatoria)
console.log(capitalAleatorio)

if (posicionAleatoria == 0) {
    $("#bt1").text(capitalAleatorio);
} else if (posicionAleatoria == 1) {
    $("#bt2").text(capitalAleatorio);

} else {
    $("#bt3").text(capitalAleatorio);
}





/*--------------IMAGENES DE CONTINENTES---------------------------------*/


var continente = cajaPaises[numeroAleatorio]["continente"];

if (continente == "Asia") {
    $('#imagenes').attr('src', 'asia.jpg')

} else if (continente == "Oceania") {

    $('#imagenes').attr('src', 'australia.jpg')

} else if (continente == "Europa") {
    $('#imagenes').attr('src', 'mapa-de-europa.jpg')
} else if (continente == "America") {
    $('#imagenes').attr('src', 'america.jpg')
} else if (continente == "Africa") {

    $('#imagenes').attr('src', 'AFRIQUE.jpg')
}

/*-------------FIN DE IMAGENES-----------*/




//--------CONTADOR DE TIEMPO-----------------------------------------


var n = 0;
var l = document.getElementById("number");
window.setInterval(function () {
    l.innerHTML = n;
    n++;
}, 1000);

//-------------FIN CONTADOR DE TIEMPO-------------
```

});

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Juego</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilo.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body class="body2">
  
  <div id="number"></div>
   
   <div class="contenido">



<div class="continentes">
 <img  id="imagenes" src="mapa-de-europa.jpg" alt="mapa de europa">
 <img  class="imagenes1" src="Asia.jpg" alt="Asia">
 <img  class="imagenes1"  src="AFRIQUE.jpg" alt="africa">
 <img  class="imagenes1"   src="australia.jpg" alt="Oceania">
 <img  class="imagenes1"   src="america.jpg" alt="America">
 </div>
 
<!----RELOJ-------------------->


    <div id="reloj"></div>

 
 <!-------FIN RELOJ--------------->




  <div class="grid-container">
  
  <div class="a"><button class="pais" id="pais1"></button></div>
  <div class="b"><button class="opciones" id="bt1"></button></div>
  <div class="c"><button class="opciones"id="bt2"></button></div>
  <div class="d"><button class="opciones" id="bt3"></button></div>
  

 
 
 
 
   
       </div>
       
       
       
    </div>
    

   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Encontré la solución a mi propia pregunta y siento la necesidad de compartirlo ya que he estado varios días intenándolo...Y por supuesto agradecidísima a quien me ha contestado!**