# Mostrar texto aleatorio de una cadena en Javascript

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código hace lo que necesito pero me gustaría que se pueda adicionar más texto, pero crecería demasiado el archivo si tengo 1000 nombres.

```
function alea() {
    variable    = new Array();
    variable[0] = 'David';
    variable[1] = 'Lucas';
    variable[2] = 'Nick';
    variable[3] = 'Paul';
    variable[4] = 'Marcos';
    variable[5] = 'Luis';
    aleatorio   = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    return variable[aleatorio];
}
```

He visto que usan **IndexOf()** y **Replace()** para trabajar con cadenas… Me facilitaría cuando tenga que agregar cientos de nombres, pero no lo entiendo.

```
var notificacion = {
    "Variable1": ["David", "John", "Paul", "Mark", "James", "Andrew", "Abel\r\n"],
    "Contenido": "<p><strong>[variable1]<\/strong> Salio del sistema.<\/p>",
};
var z = Math.floor(Math.random() Variable1.length);
if (Contenido.indexOf([varible1]) + 1) {
    var mensaje = Contenido.replace([varible1], Variable1[z])
}  else {
    var mensaje = Contenido.replace([variable1], Variable1[z])
}
return mensaje;
```

Comment: No queda clara tu pregunta, por favor considera leer [ask]

Comment: estoy revisando estas preguntas pero sigo sin entender https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282030/texto-en-bot%c3%b3n-aleatorio-javascript      y    https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342202/buscar-un-caracter-en-una-cadena-de-texto-crear-array-y-dar-un-valor-aleatorio

Comment: Que quieres hacer? no llego a entender

Comment: que me muestre un mensaje con un nombre aleatorio,  que lo toma de una cadena que puede contener 1000 nombres y no estar poniéndolo de a uno por cada linea. como el primer codigo.. en el segundo fragmento de codigo es lo que vi en un script pero alli ya lo trabaja con la frase que era mas lo quite solo deje una parte pero esa es la  idea. como mencione en el comentario anterior unas preguntas que hicieron otros es algo muy similar.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de revisar las preguntas de otros y las respuestas que le dieron opte por dejarlo así:

```
function textoAleatorio() {
    var texto = "David,John,Paul,Mark,James,Andrew,Abel";
    opciones = texto.split(",");
    posicionAleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random() * opciones.length);
    return opciones[posicionAleatoria];
}
```